# TFDDataMove csv file bug fix

Tags: delphi, csv

I am using Delphi XE5 Update 2.  There is a bug in the TFDDataMove component for csv files.  Instead of using a comma for the delimiter, it uses a semicolon making it unusable for csv files.  Does anyone know whether a fix for this has been released by Embarcadero or by FireDac's author? If yes, where do I find it?

Alternatively, can I subclass the component to fix this myself, as Embarcadero does not supply the source code for the FireDac components?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The `TFDDataMove` has so many bugs. So in not worth try to fix it (even was deprecated in XE7). You best option is write your own method to export to a csv (is very straightforward). Check this sample [`Poor Man’s CSV Export`](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2013/11/06/poor-mans-csv-export/).

Note : If you can migrate to XE7 you can use the `TFDBatchMove` component.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I have already seen the article in your link.  While it works, i wanted something more RAD and hoped there was a fix for the TFDDataMove component.  Am not ready to spend the money to upgrade to XE7 quite yet.  For my needs, XE5 is adequate.